# Decoding of old style JPEG-in-TIFF data is not supported

Tags: java, tiff

I need to display the 3rd page of scanned tiff files. i used the code

```
TIFFReader reader = new TIFFReader(new File(pathOfFile));    
RenderedImage image = reader.getPage(2);
```

its sometimes work. and show error : Decoding of old style JPEG-in-TIFF data is not supported.
I used aspriseTIFF.jar

then how i solve this problem.
please reply.
thanks in advance

Comment: 'new File(f1.getAbsolutePath())' is just a convoluted way of writing 'f1'. You don't need pointless complications like this.

Comment: What `TIFFReader` class are you using? You could try using my `TIFFImageReader` plug-in for ImageIO, available here: https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys It does support (some) versions of "old-style" JPEG in TIFF. If you attach some of the images that isn't supported, I could test them for you.

Comment: @EJP Unless `f1` is a file-like object with a `getAbsolutePath()` method but is not an instance of `File` or a `File` subclass.

Comment: @EJP, JAB, I edited the question so that you can focus on the problem...

Comment: @user3437103 you should not rollback edits when they are justified.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have run into is that "old style" [JPEG compression in the TIFF format](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html) (`compression == 6`), is not supported in the library you use.

This is quite common I guess, as "old-style" JPEG compression is deprecated in TIFF, because it was never fully specified. And because of this under-specification, various vendors implemented it in different, incompatible ways. Support was dropped in favor for TIFF compression 7, `JPEG`.

Unfortunately, old TIFF files using this compression still exists, so you need to find another library. The good news is that you can use ImageIO and a proper plug-in.

Using a TIFF `ImageReader` plug-in, like the one from my [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) open source project, you should be able to do this:

```
// Create input stream
try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)) {
    // Get the reader
    ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(input).next();

    try {
        reader.setInput(input);

        // Read page 2 of the TIFF file
        BufferedImage image = reader.read(2, null);
    }
    finally {
        reader.dispose();
    }
}
```

(sorry about the `try/finally` boiler-plate, but it *is* important to avoid resource/memory leaks).

Comment: how do you know how many pages has the TIFF file? I couldn't find any example of TwelveMonkeys library to extract single pages to a JPEG or PNG format from a multi-page tif file.

Comment: Please don't use comments for questions. But... This is standard ImageIO functionaliy, and works for any `ImageReader`, simply use [`reader.getNumImages(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageReader.html#getNumImages(boolean)).

Comment: try-with-resource for Java7+ `try (ImageInputStream input = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)) { ... }` will save one `try { } finally { }` (but not the `reader.dispose()` though)